# Ruby on Rails - how to get all odd users

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I would like to get all users where user_id is odd like (1,3,5,7,9,11...)
Is there any easy option to do it?

`@fed = Users.all`

Comment: "Odd" is 1, 3, 5, even is 2, 4, 6.

Comment: Why? Do you want to format each seond user differently? Then there are better approches, which also work when a user in the middle is deleted. You should think of the user_id as an id and not as a number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@fed = Users.where("(id % 2) > 0").all # odd
@fed = Users.where("(id % 2) = 0").all # even
```

Comment: There's also a MOD function, i.e. `User.where('MOD(id, 2)')` returns odd ids.

Comment: @stefan: That's interesting. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 0):

using mod function is best way to find odd results. `User.where('MOD(id,2)')`